# Why is BaseFieldDefinition::getDisplayOptions($display_context) returning NULL

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to get the weight of each field (of a form) in its display.

```
$fields = $entityManager->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type, $bundle);

foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_definition) {
  $field_definition->getDisplayOptions('form'); //returns NULL
}
```

This returns NULL. $field_definition definitely has stuff inside of it. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getFieldDefinitions()` method returns NULL if the field is not displayed. From the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/function/BaseFieldDefinition%3A%3AgetDisplayOptions/8.4.x):

> Return value
>
> array|null The array of display options for the field, or NULL if the
>   field is not displayed.

The code below is responsible for returning the correct value:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDisplayOptions($display_context) {
    return isset($this->definition['display'][$display_context]['options']) ? $this->definition['display'][$display_context]['options'] : NULL;
  }
```

As you can see the `$this->definition['display'][$display_context]['options']` array has to be set. If it isn't set the method returns NULL.

Comment: Thanks. So how is this set? I am simply trying to sort the fields depending on how they appear in the form. They are, by default "sorted" by machine name. Is there a way to find out how they appear in the form? This is why I was going for getDisplayOptions()

Comment: I guess that you have to move them from the disabled section into the display section of the form display. The displayed field options should then return by calling `getDisplayOptions()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure what was going on before, but I managed to get a return value, but all I am getting back is an array with one entry: `'type' => string(6) "hidden"`. I am not getting the other values per the doc, like "weight" ... etc. I looked at my paragraphs type and everything is displayed as normal in there (the view mode is default and the format is set to rendered entity, which I guess is the paragraph entity itself), not sure what is going on?